# jQuery drop down menu disappearing when embedded form prompts for input

Tags: jquery, megamenu

I am having an issue with a jquery dropdown/mega menu. One of the drop downs contains a form if a user clicks inside one of the form fields and is prompted for a 'remembered' user name & then tries to hover over the user name and select it, the whole drop down disappears.  It looks like the element that is being hovered over is losing focus to the form popup prompt.

How can I stop this from happening? (fiddle below)

```
"use strict";

$('.mega-menu > ul > li:has( > ul)').addClass('menu-dropdown-icon');
//Checks if li has sub (ul) and adds class for toggle icon - just an UI


$('.mega-menu > ul > li > ul:not(:has(ul))').addClass('normal-sub');
//Checks if drodown menu's li elements have anothere level (ul), if not the dropdown is shown as regular dropdown, not a mega menu (thanks Luka Kladaric)

$(".mega-menu > ul").before("<a href=\"#\" class=\"mega-menu-mobile\">Navigation</a>");

    // allow clicks inside menu (forms and such)
    $(".mega-menu").click(function(event) {
        console.log('clicked inside menu');
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
    //If width is more than 943px dropdowns are displayed on hover
    $(".mega-menu > ul > li").hover(function(e) {
        if ($(window).width() > 943) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).children("ul").stop(true, false).fadeToggle(150);
        }
    });
    //If width is more than 943px dropdowns are displayed on hover

    $(".mega-menu > ul > li").click(function() {
        console.log('clickiung')
        if ($(window).width() <= 943) {
            $(this).children("ul").fadeToggle(150);
        }
    });

    // hide all menus if a click is registered outside
    $(document).click(function(event) {
        console.log('clicked outside');
        if ($(window).width() > 943) {
            $('.mega-menu > ul > li').children("ul").fadeOut(150);
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a7o6fs0b/

Based on: https://codepen.io/riogrande/pen/MKXweV

GitHub Link: https://github.com/marioloncarek/megamenu-js

Comment: Post your code here, not just at a remote site. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to make it executable.

Answer (score 0):

you can check to see if the clicked target is an Input field and then stop the menu from hiding.

In your JS file,

```
//If width is more than 943px dropdowns are displayed on hover

$(".mega-menu > ul > li").click(function() {
    console.log('clicking');

    if($(event.target).is(":input")){
        console.log("input field");
    } else {
        console.log("not input field");
        if ($(window).width() <= 943) {
            $(this).children("ul").fadeToggle(150);
        }
    }
});
```

Working Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/a7o6fs0b/15/

Comment: no this is not the issue - if you have a form popping up remembered user  names/form data etc. your menu item will still disappear

Comment: click on your user name field (in your fiddle) and try to select one of the user names.  the drop down will disappear.